# Delete row is working when clicked twice in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a delete button but the delete button is only working when clicked twice for the first time.

After deleting one row the button is working perfectly fine i.e. it is deleting row in one click only.

I am not sure why I am seeing this behavior.Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks.

```js
function delRow() {
  $('input[type="button"]').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" class="graphtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="headingalign" width="10%">Links</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="34%">Desciption</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="17%">Image</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="17%">URL</td>
      <td class="headingalign" width="10%"></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="row">
      <xsl:for-each select="//faml/response/quicklinkresponsedto/quicklink/quicklinkdto">
        <xsl:variable name="style">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">AlterRow2</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>AlterRow1</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <tr class='{$style}'>
          <xsl:variable name="txn_search">
            <xsl:value-of select="search" />
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="txn_desc">
            <xsl:value-of select="desc" />
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="txn_url">
            <xsl:value-of select="url" />
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="txn_img">
            <xsl:value-of select="img" />
          </xsl:variable>
          <td>
            <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch">
              <option value="S">Select</option>
              <option value="G">Guides</option>
              <option value="T">Templates</option>
              <option value="V">Videos</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input name="flddesc" value="{$txn_desc}" maxlength="55" size="75" /></td>
          <td><input name="fldimg" value="{$txn_img}" maxlength="45" size="45" /></td>
          <td><input name="fldurl" value="{$txn_url}" maxlength="35" size="35" /></td>
          <td><input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" class="DeleteButton" type="button" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="row">
      <xsl:for-each select="//faml/response/quicklinkresponsedto/quicklink/quicklinkdto">
        <xsl:variable name="style">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 0">AlterRow2</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>AlterRow1</xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <tr class='{$style}'>
          <xsl:variable name="txn_search">
            <xsl:value-of select="search" />
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="txn_desc">
            <xsl:value-of select="desc" />
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="txn_url">
            <xsl:value-of select="url" />
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="txn_img">
            <xsl:value-of select="img" />
          </xsl:variable>
          <td>
            <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch">
              <option value="S">Select</option>
              <option value="G">Guides</option>
              <option value="T">Templates</option>
              <option value="V">Videos</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input name="flddesc" value="{$txn_desc}" maxlength="55" size="75" /></td>
          <td><input name="fldimg" value="{$txn_img}" maxlength="45" size="45" /></td>
          <td><input name="fldurl" value="{$txn_url}" maxlength="35" size="35" /></td>
          <td><input onClick="return delRow()" tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" class="DeleteButton" type="button" /></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So what issues you are facing?

Comment: @jishansiddique it's in the question: `the delete button is only working when clicked twice for the first time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you have put a jQuery event handler inside the function, so the first click adds the event handler, and it only runs on the second click. The additional problem there is that every other click adds another handler.

You've not shown exactly how you call `delRow()`, but you can fix the problem by using a delegated event handler:

```
$('table').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
```

Comment: ```onClick="return delRow()";```  in the delete button only. I have updated the question too

Comment: Ok, then you definitely need to remove that and use the delegated handler I showed in the question. Inline event attributes should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how am i supposed to call this event since i have other buttons too on my screen cz of which it doesn't seems to be working for me

Comment: That's the beauty of delegated event handlers - it works for any elements in the page no matter when they are added. You may need to change `$('table')` to `$(document)`, I just assumed the `table` was present in the DOM when the page loads

Comment: I have tried ```$(document)``` too as you said but it still not working for me. Its working fine when i used the code in jsfiddle tho

Comment: Check your HTML. It looks like the XSL is creating invalid HTML output